How can I use the Llama 3.1 model in my app without using an API?
I want to use the Llama 3.1 8B LLM in my web app without relying on any external API.
I believe that models in GGUF format are best suited for my needs. My plan is to use the user's CPU for text generation. I think this is feasible because I was able to use LM Studio offline on my laptop (which has no GPU). I downloaded the Llama 3.1 model, and the application worked well. The text generation speed was acceptable.
